# As part of Jmeter Integration with Azure pipeline and how to increase the HEAP SPACE

Tags: performance, azure-devops, jmeter, cicd, jmeter-plugins

As Part of Jmeter integration with Azure pipeline and executed test in Azure Pipeline with 10users and 5users are in active state and 5users are in finished state.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp14z.png)

After downloading the logs I can see as **OutofMemory(JAVA HEAP SPACE)** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3elmR.png)

I guess due to this JAVA Heap size space issue only half vusers are in active state and remaining vusers are coming out as finished state.

Could any on please help me

Answer (score 0):

By default [JMeter 5.5 comes with 1 GB of JVM heap space](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter#L166)

If you want to increase it the easiest way is to define `HEAP` [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and set as much as you want there.

Something like:

```
export HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"  && ./jmeter.sh in -t your-test.jmx .....
```

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)